# How can I get this rating component automatically centered for both mobile and desktop version?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get this rating component automatically centered for both mobile and desktop version?  See link to inspect code

https://oshanedesign.github.io/interactive-rating-component/

[image]

Comment: yes, through CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.rating-content {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #212832;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these additional styling to **.rating-content** class.

```css
.rating-content{
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```